# Go, using other packages in the same project

Tags: go, import, module, directory-structure

I have the following situation, where I can't use `romanNumerals` in `romanserver`, inside a folder in my module directory.

[image]

```sh
go run romanserver/main.go
```

```sh
romanserver/main.go:13:2: no required module provides package github.com/BuddhiLW/roman/romanNumerals; to add it:
        go get github.com/BuddhiLW/roman/romanNumerals
```

I want to upload the roman project to GitHub containing both `romanNumerals` and `romanserver`. Of course, I would like to export variables from one another.

I'm still confused about how that is done in Go.

**EDIT**: I deleted go.mod in both `romanNumerals` and `romanserver`, and now everything is working, just like
Cerise Limón pointed out.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a single go.mod file at the root of the project.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Funny how I was trying that earlier and it didn't work. I think I hadn't added `require` in `roman/go.mod` earlier.